# How to add zero number to some nober with help of Loop?

Tags: c#, string, for-loop, padding

I have problem with adding a Zero-padding with for loop... here is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "12";

        for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
        {
             Console.WriteLine(str.PadLeft(i, '0'));
             Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output of this is:

```
12
12
012
0012
00012
000012
```

Why are first two values repeated?

The output that I whant to get is:

```
12
012
0012
00012
000012
```

tnx for help

Comment: It might be a clue that the parameter is called _total width_ in `public string PadLeft(int totalWidth);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Padleft takes the string and adds zeros to the left up to the length of i.

Example:

```
string str = "12";
str.PadLeft(1, '0') // 12
str.PadLeft(2, '0') // 12
str.PadLeft(3, '0') // 012
str.PadLeft(4, '0') // 0012
```

Comment: Also, very good explanation, realy thanks :D, so I need to increase my beginig "i" to have output that i whant

Comment: There are so many ways to do this..for example,you can keep your code and add str.Length to i(start i from 0)..

Comment: YES, it helps, i did this to my code: for(var i = str.Length; i <= 6; i++)

Answer (score 3):

From [`String.PadLeft(Int32, Char)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> A new string that is equivalent to this instance, but right-aligned
>   and padded on the left with as many paddingChar characters as needed
>   to create a length of totalWidth. **However, if totalWidth is less than
>   the length of this instance, the method returns a reference to the
>   existing instance. If totalWidth is equal to the length of this instance, the method  returns a new string that is identical to this instance.**

That's why when `i` is `1` or `2`, your result will be the same as `12`.

You should start your loop `int i = 2` instead of `int i = 1`.

```
string str = "12";
for(var i = 2; i <= 6; i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine(str.PadLeft(i, '0'));
}
```

Output will be;

```
12
012
0012
00012
000012
```

Here a <kbd>[**`demonstration`**](http://ideone.com/sPXmuG)</kbd>.

By the way, `Console.ReadLine()` seems pointless in your case since you don't read anything in your console.

Answer (score 2):

First parameter of the `PadLeft` method is the total lenght of the string.Since the length of your string is `2`, it only add zeros to the left when `i` becomes `3`.

If you start `i` from `2` then you will get the expected result.